# Swift danielgindi/Charts - Pie Chart Slice Space Problem

Tags: android, ios, charts, pie-chart, swift5

I'm trying to make a pie chart using the library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.

When I tried to adjust the slice space, I saw that slice space is not the same everywhere. But I could not solve this problem.

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVd8t.png)

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet private weak var pieView: PieChartView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupPieChart()
    
}

    func setupPieChart(){
        pieView.rotationAngle = 0
        pieView.rotationEnabled = false
        pieView.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false
        pieView.drawSlicesUnderHoleEnabled = true
        pieView.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false
        pieView.usePercentValuesEnabled = true
        pieView.legend.enabled = false
        
        var entries : [PieChartDataEntry] = Array()
        entries.append(PieChartDataEntry(value:  70))
        entries.append(PieChartDataEntry(value: 30))
        
        let dataSet = PieChartDataSet(entries: entries, label : "")

        dataSet.sliceSpace = 10
        
        let x_pie_color = NSUIColor(hex: 0xEAE2F2)
        let c_pie_color = NSUIColor(hex: 0xA87EC9)
        let x_text_color = NSUIColor(hex: 0x4a0ca0)
        let c_text_color = NSUIColor(hex: 0xFFFFFF)
        
        dataSet.colors = [x_pie_color, c_pie_color]
        dataSet.valueColors =  [x_text_color, c_text_color]
        dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
        pieView.data = PieChartData(dataSet: dataSet)

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try and increase the hole radius percent to some favorable value that will help adjust the spacing such that it's similar to the spacing. It worked for me. Something like this.

```
pieView.holeRadiusPercent = 0.10
```